# Find Generalized Series with Symbolic Variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, series-expansion

```
CoefficientList[Series[Exp[x], {x, a, 3}], x]
```

Gives the following expression,
$$
\left\{-\frac{1}{6} e^a a^3+\frac{e^a a^2}{2}-e^a a+e^a,\frac{e^a a^2}{2}-e^a a+e^a,\frac{e^a}{2}-\frac{a e^a}{2},\frac{e^a}{6}\right\}
$$
However, I'd like to be able to find what the generalized coefficient formula should be for any number of terms. Sadly, I cannot give `Series` a symbolic argument for `n` and `SeriesCoefficient` doesn't seem like what I'm looking for either.

The values should match the original expression, so if $a=0.5$ then: $${0.996102, 1.03045, 0.41218, 0.274787} $$

I want to find a closed form for the collected coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the "formula" for what `CoefficientList[Series[f[x], {x, a, n}], x]` gives.  If you want the term associated with $x^j$, that is the following:

```
c[j_, n_] := Sum[Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(k - j) a^(k - j) (D[f[x], {x, k}] /. x -> a)/k!, {k, j, n}]
```

Here is a specific example:

```
f[x_] := Exp[x]
n = 3;

CoefficientList[Series[f[x], {x, a, 3}], x]
(* {E^a - a E^a + (a^2 E^a)/2 - (a^3 E^a)/6, E^a - a E^a + (a^2 E^a)/2, E^a/2 - (a E^a)/2, E^a/6} *)

c[j_, n_] := Sum[Binomial[k, j] a^(k - j) (D[f[x], {x, k}] /. x -> a)/k!, {k, j, n}]
Table[c[j, n], {j, 0, n}]
(* {E^a - a E^a + (a^2 E^a)/2 - (a^3 E^a)/6, E^a - a E^a + (a^2 E^a)/2, E^a/2 - (a E^a)/2, E^a/6} *)
```

This just uses the definition of a Taylor series and the binomial theorem.

But if you just want the "formula" for what `Series` does, then the following is maybe what you want:

```
n = 3
Series[f[x], {x, a, n}] // Normal
(* E^a + E^a (-a + x) + 1/2 E^a (-a + x)^2 + 1/6 E^a (-a + x)^3 *)
c[j_, n_] := (x - a)^j (D[f[x], {x, j}] /. x -> a)/j!
Table[c[j, n], {j, 0, n}]
(* {E^a, E^a (-a + x), 1/2 E^a (-a + x)^2, 1/6 E^a (-a + x)^3} *)
```

Comment: `Table[c[j, n], {j, 0, 2}]` and `CoefficientList[Series[f[x], {x, a, 2}], x]` look different to me

Comment: You are correct.  I forgot to include the `(-1)^(k - j)` term.  I'll correct that now.

Answer (score 5):

With [`SeriesCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html), the order and expansion point can be symbolic.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

coef[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x], {x, a, n}]
```

[image]

Verification,

```
Sum[coef[n]*(x - a)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* E^x *)
```

**EDIT:**

Comparing [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html)s

```
m = 20;

CoefficientList[Sum[coef[n]*(x - a)^n, {n, 0, m}], x] == 
 CoefficientList[Series[Exp[x], {x, a, m}], x]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Much nicer, I have to admit (+1)!

Comment: I know I sound crazy, but I don't think this matches `CoefficientList` because it isn't monomials?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you want the following is your friend

```
Table[CoefficientList[Series[Exp[x], {x, a, placeholder}], x] // 
   First, {placeholder, 0, 17}] // 
 FindSequenceFunction[#, order + 1] &
```

> `Gamma[1 + order, -a]/Gamma[1 + order]`

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there anyway to get rid of the incomplete gamma function?

Comment: @Torkoal You are very welcome. To answer the question, `FullSimplify` should do the trick I think, modulo assumptions that you would perhaps need to feed into it.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to match the values of the original expression (I've listed them in the question)

Comment: @Torkoal this does not make sense, since I am taking the command you wrote and keep the highest term in the expansion. Then I just found the pattern. I did not change anything

Comment: I guess I was hoping to find a closed form expression for the collected coefficients

Comment: @Torkoal oh I see now. My mistake. I did not realize this at first. I thought you wanted the leading term for arbitrary order.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible, but yes exactly that!